# How do I generate a mask of the skin tones in an image?

Tags: photoshop, blur, layers, masks

I'm using a sequence of operations to smooth the skin of the body. What I'm doing is this:

- high-pass
- surface blur
- invert
- blend mode: linear light

At this point, what I usually do is to create a black mask and paint with white using the brush. 
Would it be possible, instead, to create a layer mask with high-pass filter? I tried doing it but I'm not seeing anything happening. Can someone tell me the procedure I should follow?

Comment: Are you saying you want to generate the skin softening mask, rather than painting it by hand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The high pass filter is not something that can generate a mask of the skin tones within an image, hence why you wouldn't see much success trying to use it for this purpose.

One possible solution would be to use PhotoShops `Select` → `Color Range...` option.

I think in CS6 onwards there's an option in the `Select` drop-down box of "Skin Tones"

[image: Screen shot of Color Range Dialogue in PhotoShop]

This can be used to generate a selection of the skin tones, then you could use that selection as the mask for your skin soften effect.

In my example image it did a reasonable job of selecting skin tones:

[image]

The mask would probably still require cleaning up a bit by hand, as the `Color Range` function is naturally going to pick up some areas of similar colour that are not actually skin.